# Custom page classes not showing up in code

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I tried adding page classes via Appearance => Menus => Screen Options => CSS Classes, but when I update my pages the classes don't show up.
I tried with another theme, it works, so my problem is theme-related. I didn't develop this theme, I took it back from another developer. Can someone explain me what I should look for in the code to make it back to normal?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a couple of things, where to look first.

Look for some standard functions are in the templates file such as `body_class()`, `post_class()`. As it print standard Wordpress used class within the context it needs to.

If its more menu related look for `add_filters()` within the **functions.php** filters that allow css to be added or removed such as.

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'some_function_called' , 10 , 2);
function some_function_called($classes, $item){
     if(is_single() && $item->title == "Blog"){ //Notice you can change the conditional from is_single() and $item->title
             $classes[] = "special-class";
     }
     return $classes;
}
```

Best of luck.

Comment: It was indeed something like
    add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'some_function_called' , 10 , 2); 

in "functions.php". Thank you.